# Stub action name in rails rspec.

Tags: rspec

I am trying to stub the action name to test a view that uses it.

```
RSpec.describe 'user/new.html.erb', type: :view do
before helper.stub!(:action_name).and_return('new')

it 'displays the form to create a new client' do
assign :user, build(:user)

render

expect(rendered).to match 'Upload Image'
end
end
```

When I run the test I am getting

```
undefined method `stub!' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: your `helper` is `nil`, that's why you are getting that error. Where did you define your `helper`? show the full code please. Also, fixe the current code's formatting please.

Comment: I think you should wrap code inside before to block: `before { ... }`